# A sequence with variables, find the $mn^{th}$ term given the $m^{th}$ and the $n^{th}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I was trying to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450403/if-the-mth-term-of-an-arithmetic-progression-is-frac1n-and-the-nth-te) question, but I'm getting a wrong answer. The question is:

If the $m$th term of an arithmetic progression is $\frac{1}{n}$ and the $n$th term is $\frac{1}{m}$ then prove that the sum to $mn$ terms is $\frac{mn+1}{2}$

Let's say the sequence goes like this: $x+a, x+2a, x+3a, ...$ so that the $n^{th}$ term is $x+na=\frac 1m$ and the $m^{th}$ term is $x+ma=\frac 1n$ . We divide the equations such that

$\frac {x+ma}{x+na}=\frac mn$ $\to$ $nx+mna=mx+mna$ , so $m=n$ . Therefore, $x+\frac 1m =\frac 1m$ , so $x=0$

Then, $0+ma=\frac 1n$ , so $a=\frac {1}{mn}$

The $(mn)^{th}$ term is $x+mna$, which is equal to $1$ . What is the mistake here? Thanks.

EDIT

There is another problem because is $m=n$ , division by $0$ works: If we subtract the two equations, we get $a(m-n)=\frac {m-n}{mn}$ and if we divide both sides by $0$ we get the correct answer of $a=\frac {1}{mn}$

Comment: A [question about the same AP](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450403/if-the-mth-term-of-an-arithmetic-progression-is-frac1n-and-the-nth-te) was asked very recently. It is different from yours in that you are asking "where is the mistake."

Comment: @AndréNicolas yes that was the one I was trying to solve

Comment: why should it be that $mx = nx$ implies $m = n$? It could be $x = 0$?

Comment: @AlexWhite Yea your right I'm assuming that $x \not =0$ but then using this result I get $x=0$

Comment: What @AlexWhite says is the reason. In fact, given that $mx = nx$ and you know that $m \neq n$ (because otherwise there is simply not enough data to answer the question), we can conclude that $x = 0$, necessarily. In fact, you can't get $a = \frac1{mn}$ without assuming that $m \neq n$. So if $x = 0$, then you can't conclude from $mx = nx$ that $m = n$; that conclusion is not valid.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR So $x=0$ . But you still get $a=1/mn$ and if you plug that into $x+amn$ you still get that the $mn^{th}$ term is equal to $1$.

Comment: The reason we get the correct answer is that $m-n\ne 0$, so you can indeed divide by $m-n$.  And why does it bother you that the $mn$-th term is $1$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas because I thought the question asked about the $mn^{th}$term, I forgot it asked about the sum to the  $mn^{th}$ term.

Comment: @Ovi: You can't get $a = \frac1{mn}$ without assuming $m \neq n$, and you can't $m = n$ without assuming $x = 0$. For example, consider $m = n = 2$ and $a = 3$ (instead of $\frac1{mn} = \frac14$), and $x = \frac1n - na = \frac12 - 6$. Then everything in the problem works out (the $m$th term is $\frac1n$ and the $n$th term is $\frac1m$), but you don't have $a = \frac1{mn}$. Basically, you can't divide by $0$. (In the original problem, wih $m \neq n$ there it's indeed true that $a = \frac1{mn}$ and that the $mn$th term is $1$... but you can't conclude that if $m = n$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake that disappears.  From $nx=mx$ you conclude $n=m$, which you cannot unless you know $x \neq 0$.  Immediately after, you conclude $x=0$, which is all you use afterward.  As others have remarked in the comments, you have to assume $m \neq n$ or you don't have enough information, then you can conclude $x=0$.  Now given your result, the $i^{\text{th}}$ term is $\frac i{mn}$ and the sum of the first $mn$ terms is $\frac {mn(mn+1)}{2mn}=\frac {mn+1}2$ as desired.

Comment: Ohh the question asked for the sum! I understood that $m \not=n$ but I was bothered because I thought the question asked about the $mn^{th}$ term which is equal to $1$ .

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  I had missed that in the middle.  I have updated the answer.  Thanks