# If $m$th term and $n$th term of arithmetic sequence are $1/n$ and $1/m$ then the sum of the first $mn$ terms of the sequence is $(mn+1)/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

> If $m$th term and $n$th term of arithmetic sequence are $1/n$ and $1/m$ respectively then prove that the sum of the first $mn$ terms of the sequence is $(mn+1)/2$.

My Attempt ;
$$\textrm t_{m}=\dfrac {\textrm 1}{\textrm n}$$
$$\textrm a + \textrm (m-1)d =\dfrac {1}{n}$$
And, 
$$\textrm t_{n}=\dfrac {1}{m}$$
$$\textrm a+\textrm (n-1)d=\dfrac {1}{m}$$

What do I do further?

Comment: The title of the question has been truncated.

Comment: Why the `\textrm`s all over the place?

Comment: "What do I do further?" Solve for $(a,d)$ the system $$a+(m-1)d=\frac1n\qquad a+(n-1)d=\frac1m$$ and deduce the value of $$\sum_{k=1}^{nm}a+(k-1)d=anm+\frac12nm(nm-1)d$$

Comment: @ did, what is $a+(k-1)d$?

Comment: Sorry but what?

Comment: Similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450403/if-the-mth-term-of-an-arithmetic-progression-is-frac1n-and-the-nth-te

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A symmetrical (but slightly unorthodox) approach:**

Multiplying the $m$th and $n$th terms by $mn$:

$$mn\cdot \overbrace{T_m}^{\frac 1n}=m\\
mn\cdot \overbrace{T_n\;}^{\frac 1m}=n$$
As an AP is linear it only needs two points to be defined. Hence we conclude that 
$$mn\cdot T_r=r$$

Sum of the first $mn$ terms is
$$\frac {mn}2\big(T_1+T_{mn}\big)=\frac {1+mn}2\;\;\blacksquare$$

---

NB: It is clear from the above that 
$$T_r=\frac r{mn}$$
and 
$$T_1=a=d=\frac 1{mn}$$

---

See also this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nyMggxCKEo) for an interesting analytic geometry approach.

Comment: @ hypergeometric, why is AP linear?

Comment: Because the difference between consecutive terms is the same. Similarly, for a straight line $y=mx+c$, the increase in $y$ is the same for consecutive unit increases in $x$, i.e. for $\Delta x=1$, we have $\Delta y=m$.

Comment: only needs two points to define the relationship.what does it mean?  @ hypergeometric

Comment: In the straight line $y=mx+c$ the unknowns are $m,c$, which can be found given two points on the line. Similarly for the AP $a+(n-1)d$ where the unknowns are $a,d$.

Comment: @ hypergeometric,  how does it happen ::?we conclude that

Comment: The conclusion can be drawn as it holds for two points (or two terms). If it holds for only one term, the same conclusion cannot be drawn.

Comment: @ hypergeometric,  how did you get that ;$mn.T_r=r$

Comment: Note that this solution is to illustrate the beauty of exploiting the symmetry of a problem to arrive at a nice short solution. However, for exam purposes it may be safer to use the standard plug-in-the-formula method, to earn full marks :)

Comment: Because the relationship has been shown to hold for $r=m$ and $r=n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53411/discussion-between-s-ramanujan-and-hypergeometric).

Comment: @ hypergeometric,  what is r?

Comment: $r$ is the general index of the AP, i.e. the $r$-th term, $T_r=a+(r-1)d$. Usually $n$ is used but here it has already been taken for a specific purpose.

Comment: what formula did you use for sum?

Comment: $\frac N2(a+\ell)$. That should be quite enough info for you to work on.

Comment: @ hypergeometric,  how do you know that $T_1=1$?

Comment: @ hypergeometric,  and also how is a=D?

Comment: See edits. Put $r=1$ into formula to get $a$. Put $r=2$ and subtract $a$ to get $d$.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming equations created by you as equation (1) and (2) respectively.

From equation (1),

$a = \frac 1n - (m - 1)d$

Put value of a in equation (2),

$\frac 1n - (m - 1)d + (n - 1)d = \frac 1m$

$\implies (-m + 1 + n - 1)d = \frac 1m - \frac 1n$

$$\implies (n - m)d = \frac {n - m}{mn}$$

$$\implies d = \frac 1{mn}$$

Then $$a = \frac 1n - (m - 1) \cdot \frac{1}{mn}$$

$$a = \frac 1n - \frac 1n + \frac 1{mn}$$

$$a = \frac 1{mn}$$

Using sum formula -

$S_{mn}=\frac{mn}2 \left[ 2 \cdot \frac {1}{mn} + (mn - 1) \cdot  \frac {1}{mn} \right]$

Taking $\frac {1}{mn}$ common,

$= \frac{mn}2 × \frac {1}{mn}\left[ 2 + (mn - 1) \right]$

$= \frac{1}2 × \left( mn + 1) \right)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_k=a_0+kp$. Then:

$a_n=a_m+(n-m)p\\
\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}=(n-m)p\\
\frac{n-m}{nm}\frac{1}{n-m}=p\\
p=\frac{1}{nm}$

and

$a_n=a_0+np\\
a_0=a_n-np=\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m}=0$

Now we just need to calculate

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{nm}a_k=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{nm}a_0+kp= \frac{1}{nm}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{nm}k= \frac{1}{nm}\frac{(nm+1)(0+nm)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(nm+1)$

Comment: @ Jaroslaw Matlak, what is $a_k=..$?

Comment: @S.Ramanujan - it's formula for k-th element of arithmetic sequence

Comment: @ Jaroslaw Matlak,  Then $a_0$ is the first term?

Comment: @S.Ramanujan Actually it's the 0-th term. First term is $a_0+p$

Comment: @ Jaroslaw Matlak,  Then what's $P$?

Comment: @S.Ramanujan $p$ is the sequence's common difference.

Comment: @ Jaroslaw Matlak, I didn't get completely,  will you explain me here ;;http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53289/keep-typing

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_t = u_0 + a \cdot t$
$$ u_m = \frac{1}{n} $$
$$ u_n = \frac{1}{m} $$
Therefore $$ u_n - u_m = a \cdot \left( n-m \right)= \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n} $$
$$ a=\frac{1}{m \cdot n} $$
So the initial term is$$ u_n = u_0 + \frac{n}{m \cdot n} = u_0 + \frac{1}{m} = \frac {1}{m}$$
$$ u_0 = 0 $$
We have $$ u_t = \frac{t}{m\cdot n} $$
We want to determine $$\sum_{t=0}^{m\cdot n} u_t = \sum_{t=0}^{m\cdot n} \frac{t}{m \cdot n}$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^{m\cdot n} u_t = \frac{1}{m \cdot n} \sum_{t=0}^{m\cdot n} t$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^{m\cdot n} u_t = \frac{1}{m \cdot n} \frac{(m \cdot n)\cdot(m \cdot n +1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{t=0}^{m\cdot n} u_t = \frac{m \cdot n +1}{2}$$